# ejabberd: OpenSSL might not be installed on this system. docker

Tags: ejabberd

After using the ecs Dockerfile to build the image and package it into the server, the following exception information appears

```
2023-09-05 18:50:42 OpenSSL might not be installed on this system.

2023-09-05 15:54:34 =ERROR REPORT==== 5-Sep-2023::07:54:34.162563 ===
2023-09-05 15:54:34 Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:
2023-09-05 15:54:34 "load_failed, Failed to load NIF library: 'Error loading shared library libcrypto.so.1.1: No such file or directory (needed by /home/ejabberd/lib/crypto-5.0.6.3/priv/lib/crypto.so)'"
```

It is normal for me to build a docker image, with openssl-dev, openssl extension:

```
RUN apk upgrade --update-cache --no-progress  && apk add  expat  freetds  gd  jpeg  libgd  libpng libstdc++ libwebp ncurses-libs openssl-dev openssl sqlite sqlite-libs  tini   unixodbc  yaml zlib  && ln -fs /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0 /usr/lib  39.7s
```

link: https://github.com/processone/docker-ejabberd/tree/master/ecs

I could not get through this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, it seems the `mix` container image published four months ago, based in Alpine 3.17, included OpenSSL 1, and since past month, [Alpine 3.17 includes OpenSSL 3](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openssl&branch=v3.17&repo=&arch=&maintainer=). When the next ejabberd version is released, both `mix` and `ecs` images will be updated.

Until the next ejabberd release is published, you can try this:

1. First build a recent `mix` image:

```
cd docker-ejabberd/mix/
docker build -t personal/mix105 .
```

2. Use that recent `mix` image in the `ecs` Dockerfile:

```
cd docker-ejabberd/ecs/
sed -i 's|ejabberd/mix|personal/mix105|g' Dockerfile
```

3. Now build the `ecs` image:

```
docker build -t personal/ejabberd105 .
```

4. ejabberd now will start correctly:

```
docker run -it -p 5222:5222 personal/ejabberd105 live
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

2023-09-05 14:17:46.325054+00:00 [info] Loading configuration from /home/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml
2023-09-05 14:17:46.360877+00:00 [warning] Option 'log_rotate_date' is deprecated and has no effect anymore. Please remove it from the configuration.
2023-09-05 14:17:46.361015+00:00 [warning] Option 'log_rate_limit' is deprecated and has no effect anymore. Please remove it from the configuration.
2023-09-05 14:17:46.836616+00:00 [info] Configuration loaded successfully
2023-09-05 14:17:47.039276+00:00 [info] Got no NOTIFY_SOCKET, notifications disabled
2023-09-05 14:17:47.055606+00:00 [info] Building language translation cache
2023-09-05 14:17:47.213716+00:00 [info] Creating Mnesia ram table 'ejabberd_commands'
2023-09-05 14:17:47.314708+00:00 [info] Creating Mnesia ram table 'route'
2023-09-05 14:17:47.354691+00:00 [info] Creating Mnesia ram table 'route_multicast'
```